Wrong Column names on SAS
I have a table with several columns, some of which are named using numbers (e.g., 1, 2, 3, …). When I attempt to use the CATX function with these column names (e.g., CATX("+", _1, _2, _3, ..., _26)), I encounter an issue where it reports that the columns do not exist. This behavior used to work in regular SAS, but now that I’m working with SAS Grid, it no longer functions as expected. I have an error saying that those columns don't exist.

SAS names cannot start with a digit. If the name is actually 1 then you need refer to it as '1'n and not as _1.

validvarnames=any is likely enabled, and you need to use name literals with these columns. For example:
'1'n, '2'n, '3'n, etc.
To use catx() on these columns, use name literal format instead:
catx('+', of '1'n--'26'n)
To force SAS to add an underscore on these column names, set validvarname=v7:
options validvarname=v7;
SAS will replace invalid characters with underscores, and add underscores in front of columns that start with numbers.

Your table was created by, perhaps IMPORT, TRANSPOSE or some array-based pivot, and there are some numbered columns that are not present.
You can concatenate a list of variables using the OF operator.
Example:
The similar prefix (:) specifier is used to make a list of all variables that start with underscore (_)
length result $32767 ;
result = catx('+', of _:) ;

A more sophisticated variable selection can be done with SQL and DICTIONARY.COLUMNS
%let names = "" ; %* for the case of no prxmatches ;
proc sql noprint ;
  select name into :names separated by ','
  from dictionary.columns
  where libname = 'WORK' and memname = 'HAVE'
  and prxmatch ('m/^_\d+$/,trim(name))
  order input(substr(name,2),best8.);
data want;
  set WORK.HAVE ;
...
  result = catx('+', &names) ;
...

